# TextBlock exception when using multiDataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, multidatatrigger

I'm trying to add 2 triggers to the visibility property of a textblock. 
The following code causes a "TextBlock exception". Any idea why?

```
<TextBlock Name="tb2"
           Style="{StaticResource MyPageTextStyle}"
           Text="{x:Static res:MyResources.MyText}"
           Visibility="Collapsed"
           >
           <TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                           <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{BindingPath=Class1.IsBlue}" Value="true" />
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Class1.IsGreen}" Value="false" />
                           </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Setter TargetName="tb2" Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
 </TextBlock>
```

Comment: And what exactly is a "TextBlock exception"? What is the type of the exception, and its message?

Comment: Hi, this is a "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException". The additional information is only: "Initialization of System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock threw an exception"

Comment: Look at the InnerException to get more details

Comment: btw, you're missing a space between "Binding" and "Path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding triggers to textblock add triggers to textblock style... some how adding triggers directly to control will throw xaml exceptions...

try to do some thing like this...

```
<TextBlock Name="tb2" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style>
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                               <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Class1.IsBlue}" Value="true" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Class1.IsGreen}" Value="false" />
                               </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                               <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```